# Symfony controller route with requirements on uuid

Tags: php, symfony

I have an entity like this:

```
class Building
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")
     * @Expose()
     */
    private $id;

    ....
}
```

I would like to know if there is a way to specify the requirements on uuid to separate two different url like this on rest API:

```
class BuildingController extends BaseController
{   
    /**
     *
     * @Rest\Get("/buildings/{id}", requirements={"id" = "\d+"})
     */
    public function getBuildingAction($id)
    {
        //code
    }
```

`\d+` is correct for integer value but I would like to change It to uuid type because I have another route for example this:

```
 /**
 * @Rest\Get("/buildings/lot")
 */
public function getBuildingLotAction(Request $request)
{
    //code
}
```

Is possible to define uuid on requirements type?

Thanks

Comment: I actually don't understand what exactly you mean but I wonder if this helps you in any way. http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/pey5/using-a-custom-class-constant-for-route-annotation-requirements

Comment: Symfony 6.1 will introduce a `Requirement` enumeration to define some *special* requirements like dates or UUIDs/GUIDs and the like. More in [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/45528) and [this blog post](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-improved-routing-requirements-and-utf-8-parameters#a-collection-of-common-routing-requirements).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can simply put "/buildings/lot" action before /buildings/{id}.

[First route always win.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/requirements.html)

Best I could find - [this article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing.html#defining-routes) gives example of regexp, so I guess PHP regexps should work fine.

There is also [mention of Symfony expression language](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/conditions.html), though without example for annotations.

Comment: Sure but I would like to know if there is a way to declare uuid inside requirements

Comment: And the big problem is that /buildings/lot could never called because all routes buildings/ go on my getBuildingAction because there isn't difference inside their declaration for symfony

Comment: Try this regex:     /^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$/i

Answer (score 4):

As of Symfony 6.1, we can use predefined route requirements as explained in 0x6d6c comment:

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Requirement\Requirement;

#[Route('/products/{id}',
    name: 'product_show',
    requirements: ['id' => Requirement::UUID_V6]
)]
public function show(string $id): Response
```

Check the feature introduction on the [Symfony blog](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-6-1-improved-routing-requirements-and-utf-8-parameters#a-collection-of-common-routing-requirements).

Answer (score 1):

`@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="UUID")` uses UUID V1 and thus you need to use this expression:

```
/**
 *
 * @Rest\Get("/buildings/{id}", requirements={"id" = "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-1[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"})
 */
public function getBuildingAction($id)
{
    //code
}
```

If you want to catch any version of UUID you can use this `"[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[1-6][0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"`

Comment: I wanted to use it in security.yaml file for access_control

Answer (score 0):

I have used like this. it was worked for me!

```
/**
    *  @Rest\Patch("stocks/{stock}", requirements={"stock" = "[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-4[0-9a-f]{3}-[89ab][0-9a-f]{3}-[0-9a-f]{12}"})
    */
```

[There is other regex structures have give](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/f49cb6a4a2e59e066caf6177b3177b9deb6a3490/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Requirement/Requirement.php)